# How to use HTML file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to use an HTML file in my code currently I am using following line of code:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:nil];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

But the problem which I am facing is: the HTML Page contains some images, and all that images are in a folder in my project but I am not able to see that images in the HTML page at run time.

Comment: Change paths to images into your html file.

Comment: yes I did this but it is not working

Comment: you need to convert the NSData data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the possible ways to use HTML into the project,
Following code for the load HTML file into xcode project

Example 1, loading the content from a URLNSURL

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Example 2, loading the content from a string

```
    NSString *HTMLData = @"<h1>Hello this is a test</h1>";
    [webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];
```

Example 3, loading the content from a local file

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Hope this code helping to develop a application

Answer (score 4):

You can set the baseURL to your resource folder, where your images are located:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"htm" inDirectory:nil];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath];
NSURL *baseUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:resourcePath];
[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:htlmString baseURL:baseUrl];
```